# Hot reload in VS2022 does not work when loading multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I know there are a lot of people reporting issues with hot reload on vs2022; I've done a lot of reading the past couple of days.  However, my issue appears to be a little different than most.

I originally thought that I was having the same issues as others.  But while working on my code I noticed at one point that the hot reload button on the .net Maui page was a green check, so it was working.

It then dawned on me that I was only running the .net Maui app and not loading the Azure functions that went along with it.

I right clicked on my solution and selected "Set Startup Projects" again and selected both the .net Maui and the Azure functions projects and sure enough, I had the red X for the XAML hot reload button.

So it appears the hot reload for me is working if I debug the .net Maui app without the azure functions running as well.  But this leads to another issue, I can't get to some areas of the code in my .net Maui app without the azure functions providing the data back.  This is a problem because I can't create the view and it's taking a lot of starts, stops, guessing what the XAML should be then repeating.

I guessed the issue has to do with both apps being debugged. And I was right, when I selected the azure functions app to start without debugging in the "Set Startup Projects" then I got the XAML hot reload option.  This makes some of it better, but I would really like to be able to debug both apps at the same time as I work on data transmission.

Does anyone know how to get both started apps in debug mode and still have the XAML hot reload option available in VS2022 (17.3.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the same behavior debugging my solution. It's not ideal, but debugging your function app in a separate instance of Visual Studio seems to work.

Comment: This is what I have been doing. Yes, this works.